# Check if user is at bottom of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a real-time chat div on my website and I added this code to run at 1000ms intervals so the user will stay at the bottom of the chat even when new messages come:

`$("#chat-body").scrollTop($("#chat-body")[0].scrollHeight);`

However, the problem is that this way, the user can't scroll up, because at the end of the second it will take the user to the bottom of `#chat-body` anyway.  I want it to check whether the user is already at the bottom of `#chat-body` (i.e. isn't scrolling up) before taking him to the bottom when a new message arrives.

How can I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to add this code on message append? For example, the user could scroll up or down freely but when a new message appears, this code runs and the new message comes into view immediately? It seems like it would be overkill to run this every 1 sec. With that code, this comment alone would have initiated the div scroll 10 times before I posted it.

Comment: Personally, if I as the user were scrolling through old messages and the chat forced to the bottom because a new message came in, when I was trying to read up on old messages, I would be supremely irritated.  My freedom to read older messages at that point has been taken away.

Comment: Agree with Taplar, if a user is scrolling up, they are looking for a particular message to reference. To then be suddenly taken to the bottom would be unexpected. Would not pursue this..

Comment: @War10ck But it still takes the user to the bottom of a page when he gets a new message, even if he doesn't want to go down and wants to see previous chats.

Comment: @taplar Yep.  You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to get the height of the element, and add that to the `scrollTop`.  if that number is `>=` the `scrollHeight` then you're at the bottom!

```js
$(function() {
  var $scroller = $("#scroller");
  var height = $scroller.height();
  var $output = $("#output");

  $scroller.on("scroll", function(event){
    var txt = "height: " + height
            + "\nscrollHeight: " + this.scrollHeight
            + "\nscrollTop: " + this.scrollTop
            + "\nCalculated Bottom: " + (this.scrollTop + height);

    if(this.scrollTop + height >= this.scrollHeight){
      txt += "\n!!!At the bottom!!!"
    }
    $output.text(txt);
  });
});
```

```css
#scroller {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
}
#scroller p { padding: 10px; margin: 0; }
#scroller p:nth-child(even) { background-color: #EEE; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroller">
 <p>a message</p>
 <p>another message</p>
 <p>a message</p>
 <p>another message</p>
 <p>a message</p>
 <p>another message</p>
 <p>a message</p>
 <p>another message</p>
 <p>a message</p>
 <p>another message</p>
</div>

<pre id="output"></pre>
```

I'd suggest that instead of running your "scroll me to the bottom" code every 1000ms, instead just scroll to the bottom when a new message comes in && you are already at the bottom.

Also, when not at the bottom and a new message comes in, maybe show some kind of indication that there are new unseen messages below.  Slack does it like this:

[image]

Comment: discord does a similar alert bar.